# How do I add the below string to a dictionary in key value pair format

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input :

```
"name=xyz,city=bangalore,company=abc,education=BE"
```

Output :

```
{"name":"xyz", "city":"bangalore", "company":"abc", "education":"B.E"}
```

I am able to get `['name=xyz', 'city=bangalore', 'company=abc', 'education=BE']`
but am stuck on splitting the word inside the list and appending to dictionaries.

Comment: Split once more time?

Comment: How are you getting it into a `list`? The same process should work for getting it into a `dict` if you split on `=`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo `s.split(',')`? you missed an `s`...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
inp = "name=xyz,city=bangalore,company=abc,education=BE"

out = dict(x.split("=") for x in inp.split(","))
# {'name': 'xyz', 'city': 'bangalore', 'company': 'abc', 'education': 'BE'}
```